# cascading dropdown not Working in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, categories

i am trying to use cascading dropdown list in mvc. main category is working but in subcategory having some problem.it doesn't show any value when i choose from main category

in Blade:

```
   <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="cat_id">Category <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                         <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id" class="form-control">
                             <option value="">--Select any category--</option>
                             @foreach($categories as $key=>$cat_data)
                                 <option value='{{$cat_data->id}}'>{{$cat_data->title}}</option>
                             @endforeach
                         </select>
                     </div>
 
                     <div class="form-group" id="child_cat_div">
                         <label for="child_cat_id">Sub Category</label>
                         <select name="child_cat_id" id="child_cat_id" class="form-control">
                             <option value="">--Select any category--</option>
 
                         </select>
                     </div>
 
 
 @push('scripts')
 
 
 <script>
     $('#cat_id').on('change',function(e) {
        var cat_id=$(this).val();
        // alert(cat_id);
        if(cat_id !=null){
             // Ajax call
             $.Ajax({
                 url:"/backend/category/"+cat_id,
                 data:{
                     _token:"{{csrf_token()}}",
                     id:cat_id
                 },
                 type:"POST",
                 success:function(response){
                     if(typeof(response) !='object'){
                         response=$.parseJSON(response)
                     }
                     // console.log(response);
                     var html_option="<option value=''>Select sub category</option>"
                     if(response.status){
                         var data=response.data;
                         // alert(data);
                         if(response.data){
                             $('#loader').css("visibility", "visible");
 
                             // $('#child_cat_div').removeClass('d-none');
                             $.each(data,function(id,title){
                                 html_option +="<option value='"+ id +"'>" + title +"</option>"
                             });
                         }
                         else{
                         }
                     }
                     else{
                         $('#child_cat_div').addClass('d-none');
                     }
                     $('#child_cat_id').html(html_option);
                 }
             });
         }
         else{
         }
     }) </script> @endpush
```

in Route:

```
      Route::POST('/category/{id}','Admin\CategoryController@getChildByParent');
```

in article Controller:

```
        public function create()
    {
        $categories=Category::where('is_parent',1)->get();
        $photos = Photo::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $articles = Article::all();
        return view('backend.articles.create',
            compact('categories','photos','tags','articles'));
    }
```

in Category Controller:

```
     public function getChildByParent(Request $request){
        $category=Category::findOrFail($request->id);
        $child_cat=Category::getChildByParentID($request->id);
        return response()->json([$child_cat]);
            return response()->json([
            'child_cat' => $child_cat]);

    }
```

in model category:

```
        public static function getChildByParentID($id){
        return Category::where('parent_id',$id)->orderBy('id','ASC')->pluck('title','id');
    }
```

Comment: did you check request? is your sub category coming or not

Comment: there is no error